# Extra quotes in csv file

Tags: excel, csv

I have an issue with addition of extra quotes in CSV file.

For example, if I save the following text in csv file:
**Hello "hello" Hello**

Then the text would be saved as below(Can be viewed from notepad):
**"Hello" ""hello"" Hello"**

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

First, for why it happens, see the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

In particular, the part that interests this question:

7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
   appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
   another double quote.  For example:

   "aaa","b""bb","ccc"

Excel quotes text if the delimiter is a comma in order to avoid cases like `This, which has a comma in it`, since it would lead to a parsing error.

If you have no quotes inside any of your values, you could manually remove the ones excel puts around each value. Alternatively, try another delimiter.